# Java Class object in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, reflection, spring-mvc

Ok, I am using spring MVC 3.0 and I am adding a log entity as follows

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Log {

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 1000)
    private String logMessage;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Staff staff;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Calendar dateAndTime;

    @NotNull
    private Class owningClass;
}
```

I am looking at this [guide](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) for help. The question is how do I use the class object for, say Student, to find a particular student with id 10, or 20, ... 
I was thinking something like this

```
Class c = Class.forName("My.Domain.Student"); //gives the bsae class
```

This is where i am not sure what to do. I want something like

```
Student student = c.find(10);
```

How can i accomplish something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe (I currently don't have Roo projects at hand, I'm using Manning Spring Roo In Action book for reference) that you can examine the content of Spring ROO ActiveRecord pattern impementation classes and see that the location by ID is implemented via a entity manager lookup:

```
public static Course Course.findCourse(Long id) {
  if (id == null) return null;
  return entityManager().find(Course.class, id);
}
```

As you can see you can pass whatever entity class reference you like to the enitity manager to do lookup based on the class and the id.

So you basically you need to get a reference to the EntityManager and call its find() method.